# Does it worth to go for lazy loading for a Nativescript app?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am half way migrating an ionic app to Nativescript. As I was Googling I found some articles and repos about lazily loading modules in {N}.

e.g. https://github.com/sis0k0/lazyNinjas

I am not really sure why to care for lazy loading while all app files are already stored in the device. Does it have any performance improvement? If any, how?

Should I consider restructuring?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance increase you will have is mainly on loading time. As the modules are lazily loaded, your application needs to parse less code when it first loads so you get this boost. Please note that users tend to like a lot when apps open fast and are ready to use as soon as they tap them.

Comment: Good thing I asked then. As I am moving away from ionic because of the slow initial loading. Definitely worths the effort then. Thanks.

Comment: You should be aware that the initial loading with nativescript is also huge.
I'm currently developing an app that uses lazy loading and without webpack+aot it can take more than 30s to load on some devices.

Comment: this application https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng has approximately 200 modules (!!) which are lazy loaded. On my Nexus 5x device without lazy loading, the startup time was approx. 14 seconds while with lazy loading it is about 4 seconds. So yes, definitely it is worthed to implement lazy-loading for bigger Angular applications You can also bundle your app with WebPack to further improve the performance in production.